# Convert function SYS_CONTEXT in Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I'm converting Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL. I can't find a function like Oracle in PostgreSQL.
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID'); SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER'); SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER'); SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'); SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'MODULE'); SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'ACTION')

Answer (score 2):

There are no totally identical replacements in PostgreSQL. You will have to be creative. In my opinion, the best equivalents are:

- for `SESSIONID`, use the backend process ID as returned by the function `pg_backend_pid()`
- for `SESSION_USER`, use the `session_user` function (no parentheses!)
- for `MODULE` and `ACTION`, use the parameter `application_name`
- there is no equivalent for `TERMINAL` and `OS_USER`: the former makes no sense in the context of PostgreSQL, the latter makes no sense at all

Comment: `terminal` and `os_user` are provided by the SQL client to Oracle, so this could be appended to `application_name` if the information is needed.